# Torsor descriptions of $Bun_G$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, principal-bundles

The moduli stack $Bun_{SL_n}X$ of $SL_n$-principal bundles over a projective curve $X$ is a $\mathbb{G}_m$-torsor over the sublocus of $Bun_{GL_n}X$ corresponding to vector bundles with zero determinant.

Is there a similar description for $Bun_{Sp_{2n}}X$? Edit: by this I mean a description as a torsor over something (e.g. a substack of $Bun_{GL_n}X$ for $SL_n$, which is not the same as the descriptions of its objects as vector spaces + something)

Also, by a theorem of Grothendieck the map of stacks $Bun_{O_n}X\to Bun_{GL_n}X$ induces an injection at the level of moduli spaces, and I think this essentially means that $Bun_{O_n}$ is a relative gerbe over its image (is this correct?). Is it possible to describe $Bun_{O_n}$ as a torsor over something (maybe a substack of $Bun_{GL_n}X$, as for $SL_n$?)

Comment: Aren't these the stacks of vector bundles together with a chosen map $V \otimes V \to \mathcal O_X$ that is symplectic, resp., orthogonal?

Comment: Yes, so that gives you a map $Bun_G\to Bun_{GL_n}$, but I don't think it is a $\mathbb{G}_m$-torsor. On the other hand I am interested in a description of $Bun_G$ as a torsor over something.

Comment: @Macu The only group I know that acts on $\operatorname{Bun}_G$ is $\operatorname{Bun}_{Z(G)}$, which is $\operatorname{Bun}_{\mathbb Z/2}$ in both cases. So this represents it as a $\mathbb Z/2$-gerbe on a $(\mathbb Z/2)^{2g}$-torsor over an open and closed component of $\operatorname{Bun}_{G/Z(G)}$, or something like that.

Comment: OK, so the situation of $SL_n$ is more of an exception than a general pattern?

Comment: It is a general pattern: you can relate  $Bun_G$ with $Bun_H$ if $G/Z(G)$ is isomorphic to $H/Z(H)$ ($Z$ stands for the center). But probably it does not help that much.